# Sum Based on Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I currently have this code that I want to sum every quantity based on the year. I have written a code that I thought would sum all the charges in 2016 and 2017, but it isn't running correctly.

I added the two different types of `partition by` statements to test and see if either would work and they don't. When I take them out, the Annual column just shows me the quantity for that specific receipt.

Here is my current code:

```
SELECT 
  ReceiptNumber
  ,Quantity
  ,Date
  ,sum(CASE WHEN (Date >= '2016-01-01' and Date < '2017-01-01') THEN 
        Quantity 
        ELSE 0 END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY Date) 
        as Annual2016
  ,sum(CASE WHEN (Date >= '2017-01-01' and Date < '2018-01-01') THEN 
        Quantity 
        ELSE 0 END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY ReceiptNumber)
        as Annual2017
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ReceiptNumber, Quantity, Date
```

I would like my data to look like this

```
ReceiptNumber    Quantity    Date           Annual2016    Annual2017
1                5           2016-01-05     17            13
2                11          2017-04-03     17            13
3                12          2016-11-11     17            13
4                2           2017-09-09     17            13
```

Here is a sample of some of the data I am pulling from:

```
ReceiptNumber    Quantity    Date           
1                5           2016-01-05
2                11          2017-04-03
3                12          2016-11-11
4                2           2017-09-09
5                96          2015-07-08
6                15          2016-12-12
7                24          2016-04-19
8                31          2017-01-02
9                10          2017-0404
10               18          2015-10-10
11               56          2017-06-02
```

Comment: Could you add some data sample?

Comment: use temp table or VALUES for test data

Comment: Remove both `PARTITION BY`. i.e. `OVER ()`, you're already filtering the year in the CASE)

Comment: I have added sample data into my question.

@dnoeth I have just tested that, and when I do this, it simply prints the quantity in the appropriate column (2016 vs 2017), but it does not sum all of them for that year together.

Comment: Don't remove the `OVER`, just the `PARTITION BY ...`.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
Select 
..
sum(CASE WHEN (Date >= '2016-01-01' and Date < '2017-01-01') THEN 
        Quantity 
        ELSE 0 END)
        OVER () as Annual2016
sum(CASE WHEN (Date >= '2017-01-01' and Date < '2018-01-01') THEN 
        Quantity 
        ELSE 0 END)
        OVER ()as Annual2017
.. 
Where Date >= '2016-01-01' and Date < '2018-01-01'
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Is there any way to make it only print once at the very top?

Comment: @nola94 That isn't really the job of SQL Server, you would manage that in your application. I usually do this with two models, and two stored procs. One to return the data, one to return the counts. Combine the two models into a viewmodel and you have everything you need. Lovely stuff.

Comment: @nola94 - As mentioned above..Though it is achievable in sql but it has to done at application layer..

Answer (score 1):

If you want it printed only once at the top then you should run it in a separate query like:

```
SELECT YEAR(Date) y, sum(Quantity) s FROM Table1 GROUP BY YEAR(Date)
```

and then do the main query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

Easy, peasey ... ;-)

Your original question could also be answered with:

```
SELECT *, 
 (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM Table1 WHERE YEAR(Date)=2016 ) Annual2016,
 (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM Table1 WHERE YEAR(Date)=2017 ) Annual2017
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some *conditional aggreation* over a *Window Aggregate*. Simply remove both `PARTITION BY` as you're already filtering the year in the CASE:

```
SELECT 
  ReceiptNumber
  ,Quantity
  ,Date
  ,sum(CASE WHEN (Date >= '2016-01-01' and Date < '2017-01-01') THEN 
        Quantity 
        ELSE 0 END)
        OVER () as Annual2016
  ,sum(CASE WHEN (Date >= '2017-01-01' and Date < '2018-01-01') THEN 
        Quantity 
        ELSE 0 END) 
        OVER () as Annual2017
FROM Table1
```

You probably don't need the final `GROUP BY ReceiptNumber, Quantity, Date`